# Wordpress adding extra http// after https:// in admin

Tags: wordpress, https, wordpress-theming

When loading my multi-site admin, all is fine, but when I try to login to one of my sites, I get the following address:

https://http//mywebsiteurl.com.au/wp-admin/network/

It has added an extra http//, but without the ":"

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you may just need to change the Site Address (URL) for the sub-site. There are multiple ways of doing this depending on whether or not you can get into wp-admin...Have a look at the WordPress Codex for Changing the Site URL here to get you started: https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL . The WordPress Codex for Creating a Multisite Network might also be a good resource: https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network